# Riemann integrable function to the power of $p \in [1,\infty[$ is R-int. again.

Tags: definite-integrals, proof-verification

It is stated that it is sufficient to prove Riemann-integrability of $|f|^p$ for $0 \leq f \leq 1$. $(f,\psi,\varphi:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb R)$. $\checkmark$

For any $\varepsilon >0$ there exist step functions $0 \leq \psi \leq f \leq \varphi \leq 1$ so that 
$\int_a^b(\psi-\varphi)dx\leq \dfrac{\varepsilon}{p}$. $\checkmark$

Then $\psi~^p$ and $\varphi~^p$ are also step funcitons with $\psi~^p \leq f~^p \leq \varphi~^p$, **and as $\frac{d}{dx}(x^p)=px^{p-1}$ it follows from the mean value theorem of differential calculus that $\psi~^p-\varphi~^p\leq p(\psi-\varphi)$.**

Thus $\int_a^b(\psi~^p-\varphi~^p)dx \leq p\int_a^b(\psi-\varphi)dx\leq \varepsilon$ and therefore $f^p$ is integrable. $\checkmark$

What is the connection between the bold part and the mean value theorem? I tried rearranging the expressions but they just don't resemble the theorem.

Comment: What is the source where you copied this from?

Comment: @Did From my "Analysis 1" book by Otto Forster (10th edition). Only had the best experiences with it.

Comment: Note that $\varphi^p\leqslant f^p\leqslant\psi^p$, not the other way around. To explain the bold part, use the MVT to write $\psi(x)^p-\varphi(x)^p=p\xi(x)^{p-1}(\psi(x)-\varphi(x))$ for some $\varphi(x)\leqslant\xi(x)\leqslant\psi(x)$ and note that one can impose that $0\leqslant\varphi(x)$ and $\psi(x)\leqslant1$. Then, using the condition $p\geqslant1$, one sees that $\xi(x)^{p-1}\leqslant1$, QED.